# the box-sizing property doesn't work on microsoft edge

Tags: html, css

I made a parent div and three childs div inside it,
i want to make the three childs in a row by float with some margin between each other,
i made the box-sizing property to be border-box, but the property doesn't work so the margin  property value is added to the width value as shown in the image, what is the problem?

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.child {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="one child">one</div>
  <div class="two child">two</div>
  <div class="three child">three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin` is added in all box models. Only `border` and `padding` can be included.

Comment: Why are there spaces between some words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin` is added in all box models. Only `border` and `padding` can be included.

Also, you shouldn't try to implement layouts using `float` in 2022.

Use flex box, or CSS grid:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  gap: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">one</div>
  <div class="child">two</div>
  <div class="child">three</div>
</div>
```